# What is mlv video format? How can we open mlv file?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, file-extension

I recently downloaded a trial version of a proprietary software which contained videos. All the videos were of **mlv**  format and could be opened through the application. But no other video player was able to play the video. VLC media player opened the file, but showed a black screen.

I have uploaded a sample video on Google Drive.

**[mlv video file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3T9dzgBdvB1YUU0dV9mZjFwTGM/view?usp=sharing)**

- What is this **mlv** file format?
- How can I view this video?

**Source of the file**:

I have downloaded a google store app by the name "Visual Physics" by nlytn. The video was an in-app download. I think a desktop application is available too. The link is here: [nlytn](http://www.nlytn.in/visual-physics/free-trial/)

Comment: Have you done a web search already?

Comment: @slhck I have searched many websites, but didn't get any useful result. The only useful website seemed to be this: [magiclantern.fm](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=7122.0) but it too is not applicable to my situation.

Comment: I'm guessing the "trial version of a proprietary software" may have done something to the files to render them unwatchable outside it's own proprietary software. What software is it?

Comment: @Xen2050 Actually I have downloaded a google store app by the name "Visual Physics" by nlytn. I think a desktop application is available too. The link is here: [nlytn](http://www.nlytn.in/visual-physics/free-trial/)

Comment: Looks like the software's main "product" is videos on physics, I'm not sure if they'd be happy about their videos being extracted & used elsewhere... Tried contacting the developers and asking them for a solution?

Answer (score 3):

MLV is a proprietary format for Magic Lantern Video.

[MLVviewer](https://bitbucket.org/baldand/mlrawviewer/downloads/) should open the files for viweing.

Comment: Do I need to install Python for this application? Its not working, nor showing any warning.

Comment: I dont know.  try googlin for mlv viewers.  maybe you can find a different one.